# How to remove nano seconds from calculated time by subtracting two dates?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Following is the query which returns no of days, hrs, sec, and ns when a timestamp is subtracted from another date

```
to_timestamp(to_char(MR_REQ_T.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss am'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss am')- MR_DETAILS.WO_CREATION_DATE M4_DETAILS
```

its given o/p is as follows

```
+00 00:04:32.000000
```

But I don't need nano sec.(000000)to be included in it. Is there any way to remove it.

Comment: What data type do you want? That subtraction gives you an `interval`, which is being displayed in a fixed format that you can't control natively, but is correct. Are you after a string, or something else?

Comment: Data type is not necessary just need that nano seconds to be removed.

Comment: An interval (day to second) always has fractional seconds, just like a date always has a time. The data type you want to end up with will depend on what you are trying to do with the value. Do you just want a string with HH:MI:SS, or can it be multiple days?

Comment: I need the same output as I've mentioned in the question but didn't want that nano seconds